# Git: rewriting history to collapse commits with the same message and time (merging submodules)

Tags: git, mercurial

We are working on a huge project. At the beginning of development we decided to use *Mercurial* with a subrepositories feature. After 2 years of development we had 10 separated modules with a repository for every one. We found, that the subrepositories are not the best solution for us and also found that *Git* is better for us than *Mercurial*.

So, we want to:
1. Join mercurial subrepositories into one **Main** mercurial repository with preserving the full history
2. Convert this **Main** repository to *Git* repository (also with preserving history)

The first step is already done (with a good answer on stackoverflow) using hg-convert extension for every subrepository and merging them all in one.

The second step is also done, using fast-export/hg-fast-export tool. And... Everything is good, except for one thing. Due to the fact that Mercurial with subrepositories has a feature to commit to all subrepositories with one command, we were using it rather frequently. And now the history looks like this:

```
commit c6a33eb195c574cfa81469f2109c0840852a5571
Author: John
Date:   Mon Jul 1 20:26:14 2013 +0200

Add another one feature

commit fc5390a726847ef2971edd591020c5c1d2aa168b
Author: John
Date:   Mon Jul 1 20:26:14 2013 +0200

Add another one feature

commit 2477c27b361657dabeb28802f5f510f170378fc0
Author: John
Date:   Mon Jul 1 20:26:14 2013 +0200

Add another one feature
```

The reason is each of these commits is from different original subrepository. And our history tree looks like this:

```
subrepo_1/master: -A-B-C-D-E--EJ---EJM---merged---->
                              /     /
subrepo_2/master: -F-G-H-I-J--     /
                                  /
subrepo_3/master: -K-----L-M------
```

So, master branches from different submodules completely separated. If I checkout e.g. commit *F* then working directory does not contain any code from *subrepo_1* and *subrepo_3*.

We want to have only one master branch, that should look like that:

```
master: -AFK-BGK-CHK-DIL-EJM----->
```

So one commit should represent grouped change in several modules.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to collapse each group of commits in the history to one by any single command with *Git*? These commits have the same time, message and author.

   Note: "git rebase -i" doesn't seem to be a solution, because we have too many commits to make squashing manually.
2. If it is not possible to do with one *Git* command, then is it possible to write a script based on few *Git* commands?
3. My thought (thanks for @Chronial reply) is: collect a list of commits for all master-branches and sort them by time, cherry-pick each commit from the list to the new clean branch. Then use filter-branch with commit-filter to filter each group of commits with the same time/message to leave only one. Is it OK?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single command for that. You need to use `filter-branch` with a `commit-filter`. Here are the pieces you need:

1. Run `git log -1 --pretty=format:'%H %ct %P' --full-history --all` to get a parseable list of commits, their timestamps and their parents.
2. Write a script that finds the *last* of a string of same-time non-merge commits: for each commit, check if its parent have the same timestamp and are not merges (=have only one parent themselves). If so, add it to the “to-remove” list.
3. Your commit-filter will get the shas of a commit and its parent commits (see `git help filter-branch`). From (2) you should have all the information you need stored somewhere. Keep only the **last** of a string of same-time commits, by calling `skip_commit` for all the others and `git commit-tree` (both without arguments) for the ones you want to keep.

I would ignore merges, because they complicate things and I am assuming that you don’t really have that issue for merges?

Comment: I've update the question. Does your solution is still applyable? Thanks for your reply, anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

First question from me before the solution: how big is this 10 modules? Git is not so good with a one huge repository. Instead, the recommendation is to do exactly the scenario you have right now: many submodules. Think about this before complete the migration. See this discussion: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/189776

About your question:

1. I think it's possible with *--autosquash* parameter. See: http://mcpierce.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/git-fixup-and-autosquash.html.

Comment: no, it’s not – autosquash needs `fixup!` or `squash!` in the commit message.

Comment: Our repo is just about 5000 commits and 700Mb of size, so git can easy handle this.